# Liquibase module and a variable in Spring Boot Project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, liquibase

I use liquibase in my project, and here is one of my config files:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 123
      author: m.rybalkin
      changes:
        - update:
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: code
                  value: '123'
            schemaName: prod
            tableName: config_bundle
            where: code='321'
```

Here is my build.gradle of the "liquibase" module:

```
group 'com.project.test'
version '0.1.0'

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:${liqubasePluginVersion}"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.avast.gradle:gradle-docker-compose-plugin:${gradleDockerComposePluginVersion}"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.liquibase.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.avast.gradle.docker-compose'

dependencies {
    liquibaseRuntime "org.liquibase:liquibase-core:${liquibaseCoreVersion}"
    liquibaseRuntime "org.postgresql:postgresql:${postgresqlVersion}"
}

liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            def file = new File("${projectDir}/liquibase.properties")
            if (file.exists()) {
                def props = new Properties()
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)
                props.load(is)
                is.close()

                changeLogFile props['changeLogFile']
                outputFile 'liquibase/sql-migration-bundle.sql'
                url props['url']
                username props['username']
                password props['password']
            } else {
                println "Add ${projectDir}/liquibase.properties if you want use liquibase plugin"
            }
        }
        dockerPostgres {
            changeLogFile "${projectDir}/changelog/changelog-master.yml"
            url 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5555/test'
            username 'test'
            password 'test'
        }
        runList = 'main'
    }
}

task localUpdate(dependsOn: "composeUp") {
    doFirst {
        liquibase.setProperty("runList", "dockerPostgres")
    }
    finalizedBy update
}

task localDropAll(dependsOn: "composeUp") {
    doFirst {
        liquibase.setProperty("runList", "dockerPostgres")
    }
    finalizedBy dropAll
}
```

I have two different names of my schema, a "prod" for production and a "test" for tests.
Is it possible to set a variable in my application.yml or build.gradle for changing the name when I'm testing my app and when I'm deploying it?

P.S. I also have two different profiles of my Spring app - "prod" and "test"

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can add [properties](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changelog-parameters.html) at runtime of liquibase (which can be passed in from gradle, directly from commandline, etc).

So you can for example call liquibase on the CLI:
liquibase -Durl= update